# Can't send input parameter to validator directive in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, vmware-clarity

I have a simple clarity input in my project (StackBlitz ref is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-zkrhds?file=app/my-check.directive.ts)).

```
<div class="clr-form-control" [ngClass]="{'clr-error': myInput.errors}">
    <label class="clr-control-label">My Input</label>
    <div class="clr-control-container">
        <div class="clr-input-wrapper">

            <input id="myinput" type="number" class="clr-input" min="1" max="10"
                [(ngModel)]="inputValue" #myInput="ngModel" appMyCheck="12"/>

            <clr-icon class="clr-validate-icon" shape="exclamation-circle"></clr-icon>
        </div>
        <span class="clr-subtext" *ngIf="myInput.errors?.inRange">
            Error
          </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added a validator directive `appMyCheck` to it. Here is the directive's code

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyCheck]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useClass: MyCheckDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class MyCheckDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appMyCheck') myValue;
  constructor() { }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    console.log('in validate ', this.myValue);
    return null;
  }
}
```

So I try to send a parameter `myValue` (which is sent from template code `appMyCheck="12"`) into the directive and just print it. But it always displays `undefined` value.

```
in validate  undefined
in validate  undefined
```

How can I send a parameter to the validator directive correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit your code and it work https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-nkksjf?file=app%2Fmy-check.directive.ts

```
import {Directive, Input, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMyCheck]',
   providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyCheckDirective),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class MyCheckDirective implements Validator {
  isValid: any = false;

  @Input('appMyCheck') myValue;
   set setter (state) {
    this.isValid = state;
  };
  constructor() { }

  validate(formController: AbstractControl) {
   const validationState = !this.isValid ? {
      customKey: true
    } : null;

    console.log('validation state: ', validationState);
    return validationState;
  }


 
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: Yes, thank you. 
I needed to replace `useClass: MyCheckDirective` on `useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyCheckDirective)`